# Adverb of "English"

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

Dictionary.com defines *Englishly* as *in the manner or style of the English people*. Is there an adverb for the word *English* in the sense of English language? Is there one word for saying *in English*?

Comment: Can you give context by including a sentence with the phrase you are after? I can't understand what you mean.  I also have to admit if I heard someone use Englishly I would assume they were being facetious - it's a terrible word...despite it appearing back in the 1700's.

Comment: There's the "in English", which can be used adverbially. This is short enough that you don't need a single-word adverb that means the same thing.

Comment: What is the "close" vote for? The question is on topic and shows research effort.

Comment: The close vote (not from me) was "too localized".

Comment: The second close vote (from me) was "too localized" too.

Comment: We also have *anglicism, anglicise, anglicisation*, etc. (plus *anglicization*, which really ought to be *Americanisation* imho). So I think all useful concepts are covered without *Englishy* (yuk!)

Answer (score 5):

English does not have an adverb which means "in English". We either use the word *English* by itself or say *in English*:

> We have to speak English at school.
>
> There are three verb tenses in English.

Some other languages have a one-word adverb that covers one or both of these senses, but English lacks this.

Answer (score 5):

Oddly enough, the word for "in English,[or] according to the English way" is *anglice*, from mediaeval Latin.
See, e.g., [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anglice).
Sometimes capitalised, but the OED prefers to italicise it:

> 1961    Observer 29 Mar. 29/3   Something called ‘cotton candy’ (*anglice* ‘candy floss’) is sold at seashore resorts.

Comment: Fascinatingly, this appears to be completely correct and is found in many dictionaries! Cool. But I'm not sure it's a good idea to use it; no one will know what you mean...

Comment: *Anglice* must be capitalized, and n.b. it's pronounced **ANG-li-see**.

Comment: From the example given, it looks like this was basically a Latinate invention used in dictionaries/glossaries. I can't say I've seen it ever used in a modern work, and in any case there are all sorts of weird and wonderful abbreviations used in dictionaries that wouldn't be used in ordinary parlance.

Comment: @MarkBeadles not using an obscure word for fear of not being understood, is how words become obscure in the first place.

Comment: Well, the questioner here appears to be an English language learner, not a native speaker. So obscure terms might not be the most helpful. (On another note, there's nothing intrinsically *wrong* with words becoming obscure but that's neither here nor there.)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, misread the question. There are no English adverbs for behaving in the manner of languages. Insert joke about monolingual Brits or Americans here.